# xset didnt turn on/off any led of keyboard

Tags: linux, fedora, keyboard-backlight

I have a  Tsco keyboard (TK 8019) and its backlight will turn on/off by the <kbd>SCALK</kbd> button.
<kbd>SCALK</kbd> didn't work for me in any Linux systems (it only works in Windows) and I test this script :

```
#!/bin/bash
on=$(xset -q | grep 'Scroll Lock:' | cut -d ":" -f 7)
echo $on
if [ $on == "off" ]; then
   xset led named "Scroll Lock"
else
   xset -led named "Scroll Lock"
fi
```

This worked in **Ubuntu** but in **Fedora 38** it didn't.

As I run it, it writes on or off means that it should work but **didn't change on the keyboard!**

I installed `xset` by

`sudo dnf install xset.x86_64`

[image]